# Dependency Injection in Facade layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am creating an application and I am using Façade design pattern, in which request will go through 
**Controller (webApi) -> Façade -> Business -> Repository**
And I am using Unity config to initialize my objects (façade, business, and repository), in the controller layer I will set Unity config and initialize all objects. But my doubt is how I can pass repository object to business layer.
Like I am using repository methods call in business layer and it will definitely require repository object so I injected that in business layer constructor. See below code:

```
public class MessageBusiness : IMessageBusiness

{
    IMessageRepository _messageRepository;

    public MessageBusiness(IMessageRepository messageRepository)
    {
        _messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }
    public int AddMessage(RS.DomainEntity.Model.Message newMessage)
    {
      return  _messageRepository.AddMessage(newMessage);
    }
```

}

Now should I pass this repository object from Façade layer?

```
public class MessageFacade : IMessageFacade
{
    IMessageBusiness _messageBusiness;

    public MessageFacade(IMessageBusiness messageBusiness)
    {
        _messageBusiness = messageBusiness;
    }

   public int AddMessage(RS.DomainEntity.Model.Message newMessage)
    { 
       return _messageBusiness.AddMessage(newMessage);
    }
}
```

If not then I can I inject this repository in my business layer? OR if YES then we will need to pass this in Façade as well, it’s like passing object from one layer to another. Is that the right behavior? 
Also If you give the ans for first question then how can I perform integration testing in my Façade layer. Any idea? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Controller must contain one point where all objects will be configured by using Unity container. Facade needs to know only business,  it must not know implementation of business, thus you don't need pass repository through business layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now should I pass this repository object from Façade layer?

Not really, you don't have to. In such straightforward graph like yours, you only need a unity controller factory and facades injected into controllers. Unity will do the rest, to initialize a facade it will go for a business service and since it needs a repository, Unity will find and inject one, assuming of course you register all interfaces to implementations in advance.

Btw. I definitely recommend Unit of Work instead of Repository. UoW is more general and allows the client to access all possible repositories. You can think of it like of a container to all repositories.